# TypeError: Failed to fetch at sendMessage (script.js:9:30) at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, fetch

I'm trying to communicate with my back with a chatbot I set up. The backend has received and understands my requests but cannot respond to them. I can't understand the error or find a solution and I ask for your help. Please help me. Thanks.

I tried to check the CORS and also the formats of the information sent to the backend.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.